# How to use parser.parse in a loop?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, append

I am trying to parse to `hh:mm:ss` and store it in another list `y[]`. I used two codes, one of which is wrong and I can figure out why.

#### Wrong code

```
y=[]

for x in file_st: #file_st has datetime objects[Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:00:36]
    y = parser.parse(x['Start Time'])
print (y)
```

#### Output

```
2017-01-01 00:25:47
```

#### Right code

```
trip = []
for x in file_st:
    trip.append(parser.parse(x['Start Time']).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

#### Output (which I wanted)

```
['00:00:36', '00:02:54', '00:06:06', '00:07:28', '00:07:57', '00:10:44', '00:11:34', '00:14:57', '00:15:03', '00:17:01', '00:17:13', '00:18:28', '00:18:50', '00:23:41', '00:25:47']
```

Can someone tell the reason why there's a difference when I use the `.append()`?

I am aware `y[]` will just store one value, but why isn't that one value parsed?

Comment: In your first code sample you're changing the object that `y` refers to. Each time `y` is assigned a reference to a new object. You never save previous values. In your second code sample, your saving each value you parse by `append`ing them to the list `y` refers to.

Comment: because you didn't apply `.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` the second time

Answer (score 0):

`append` adds to the end of the array [[0]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=append#array.array.append). Whereas `=` reassigns the name to the new contents [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers).